# Download excel sheet containing Dynamic data from db and corresponding charts

Tags: java, spring, charts

I am making a tool on spring 3 which takes dynamic data from db and on click of a button it will download an excel sheet which will contain the table of dynamic data from db and corresponding charts. I am not sure which technologies to use.

Comment: Since you already have a Database containing the data, all you need is a tool to create excel in Java. Try Apache POI. https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Okay would it also create charts?

Comment: I would use JFreeChart for generating charts. They can be inserted in the excel using Apache POI. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/